# Need a good structure for manipulating XML data

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net

I am trying to come up with a good class structure for simplifying working with XML files.  I got a good start but it is inadequate.

Here's a XML file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Records>
    <Band>Black Sabbath
        <Album>
            Paranoid
            <Date>1977</Date>
        </Album>
    </Band>
    <Band>Iron Maiden
        <Album>
            Killers
            <Date>1981</Date>
        </Album>
        <Album>
            PeiceOfMind
            <Date>1983</Date>
        </Album>
    </Band>
 </Records>
```

Here are my base classes

```
Public Class XmlClassBase


    Friend _list As LinkedList(Of XmlClassListItem)
    Friend _current As LinkedListNode(Of XmlClassListItem)

    Public IncludeIfEmpty As Boolean


    Public ReadOnly Property Attributes() As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Get
            If _current Is Nothing Then
                _current = _list.AddLast(New XmlClassListItem)
            End If
            Return _current.Value.Attributes
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property Text As String
        Get
            If _current IsNot Nothing Then
                Return _current.Value.Text
            Else
                Return String.Empty
            End If
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            If _current Is Nothing Then
                _current = _list.AddLast(New XmlClassListItem)
            End If
            _current.Value.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Friend Sub New()

        _list = New LinkedList(Of XmlClassListItem)
        _current = _list.AddLast(New XmlClassListItem)

    End Sub

    Public Overridable Sub Add()

        Throw New System.Exception("Add called on base " + Me.GetType.ToString + ".")

    End Sub

    Friend Function AddInternal(NewElement As XmlClassListItem) As Boolean

        Dim NewNode As LinkedListNode(Of XmlClassListItem)
        Dim rc As Boolean


        NewNode = _list.AddLast(NewElement)
        If NewNode IsNot Nothing Then
            _current = NewNode
            rc =True
        End If

        Return rc
    End Function

End Class





Public Class XmlClassListItem


    Private _text As String


    Public Attributes As Dictionary(Of String, String)


    Public Sub New()
        Attributes = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    End Sub

    Public Property Text As String
        Get
            Return _text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _text = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

I run the xml through a routine and this is what I get out:

```
public class RecordsNode
    inherits XmlClassBase



    public class BandNode
        inherits XmlClassBase



        public class AlbumNode
            inherits XmlClassBase



            public class DateNode
                inherits XmlClassBase


                public Overrides sub Add()

                    dim NewDate as new xmlclasslistitem


                    addinternal(newDate)

                end sub


                public function HasChildren() as boolean

                    return false

                end function
End class

            private _Date as DateNode


            public sub new()

                _Date = new DateNode


            end Sub


        Public ReadOnly Property [Date] As DateNode
            Get
                Return _Date
            End Get
        End Property


        Public Overrides sub Add()

                dim NewAlbum as new xmlclasslistitem


                addinternal(newAlbum)

            end sub


            public function HasChildren() as boolean

                return false

            end function
End class

        private _Album as AlbumNode


        public sub new()

            _Album = new AlbumNode


        end sub


    public readonly property Album as AlbumNode
        get
            return _Album
        end get
    end property


        public Overrides sub Add()

            dim NewBand as new xmlclasslistitem


            addinternal(newBand)

        end sub


        public function HasChildren() as boolean

            dim Children as boolean



            return Children

        end function

End class

    private _Band as BandNode

    private _FilePath as string

    public sub new()

        _Band = new BandNode


    end sub


public readonly property Band as BandNode
    get
        return _Band
    end get
end property


public property FilePath as string
    get
        return _FilePath
    end get
    set
        _FilePath = value
    end set
end property


private sub AddElement(Doc As XmlDocument, ByRef Parent As XmlElement, ParentName As String, Child As XmlElement)


    if Parent is nothing then
        Parent = Doc.CreateElement(ParentName)
    end if

    Parent.AppendChild(Child)

end sub

private function CreateElement(Item as XmlClassBase) as boolean


    if Item.IncludeIfEmpty or Item.Text <> string.empty or Item.Attributes.Count > 0 then
        return true
    else
        return false
    end if

end Function

private function SaveElement(Doc as Xmldocument, Item as xmlclassbase, Parent as xmlelement, strParentName as string, strText as string) as xmlelement

    Dim Attribute As XmlAttribute
    dim Element As XmlElement = nothing
    dim ElementName As string
    Dim KeyValue As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)


    'if CreateElement(Item)
        ElementName = Item.gettype.name
        ElementName = ElementName.substring(0, ElementName.length - 4)
        Element = Doc.CreateElement(ElementName)
        Element.InnerText = strText
        AddElement(Doc, Parent, strParentName, Element)
        For Each KeyValue In Item.Attributes
            Attribute = Doc.CreateAttribute(KeyValue.Key)
            Attribute.Value = KeyValue.Value
            Element.Attributes.Append(Attribute)
        next
    'end if

    return Element

end Function


public function Load() as boolean

    dim Doc as xmldocument


    Doc = New XmlDocument()
    Doc.Load(_FilePath)

    LoadHelper(Doc, "Band", me)
    LoadHelper(Doc, "Band", me.Band)
    LoadHelper(Doc, "Album", me.Band.Album)
    LoadHelper(Doc, "Date", me.Band.Album.Date)

    return true

end function

public sub LoadHelper(Doc As XmlDocument, Source As String, Target As XmlClassBase)

    dim bFirstNode as boolean
    dim lisNodes as XmlNodeList
    dim r as Integer
    dim strText as string = string.empty


    bFirstNode = True
    lisNodes = Doc.GetElementsByTagName(Source)

    For Each Node As XmlNode In lisNodes

        If bFirstNode Then
            bFirstNode = False
        else
            Target.Add()
        end if

        strText = String.Empty

        For Each child As XmlNode In Node.ChildNodes
            If child.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Text Or child.NodeType = XmlNodeType.CDATA Then
                strText &= child.Value.Trim
            end if
        next

        If strText <> String.Empty Then
            Target.Text = strText
        end if

        For r = 0 To Node.Attributes.Count - 1

            Target.Attributes.Add(Node.Attributes(r).Name, Node.Attributes(r).InnerText)

        next

    next

end sub

public function Save() as boolean

    dim Records0 as xmlelement = nothing
    dim Band1 as xmlelement = nothing
    dim Album2 as xmlelement = nothing
    dim Date3 as xmlelement = nothing
    dim Dec as xmldeclaration
    dim Doc as xmldocument


    Doc = New XmlDocument()
    Dec = Doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", String.Empty)
    Doc.AppendChild(Dec)
    Records0 = SaveElement(Doc, me, nothing, "Records", Text)

    For Each Item As XmlClassListItem In me.Band._list
        Band1 = SaveElement(Doc, me.Band, Records0, "Band", Item.Text)
        Records0.appendchild(Band1)
    next
    For Each Item As XmlClassListItem In me.Band.Album._list
        Album2 = SaveElement(Doc, me.Band.Album, Band1, "Album", Item.Text)
        Band1.appendchild(Album2)
    next
    For Each Item As XmlClassListItem In me.Band.Album.Date._list
        Date3 = SaveElement(Doc, me.Band.Album.Date, Album2, "Date", Item.Text)
        Album2.appendchild(Date3)
    next

    If Band1 IsNot Nothing Then
        Records0.AppendChild(Band1)
    end If
    If Album2 IsNot Nothing Then
        Band1.AppendChild(Album2)
    end If
    If Date3 IsNot Nothing Then
        Album2.AppendChild(Date3)
    end If


    Doc.AppendChild(Records0)
    Doc.Save(_FilePath)

    return true

end Function

    public Overrides sub Add()

        dim NewRecords as new xmlclasslistitem


        addinternal(newRecords)

    end sub


    public function HasChildren() as boolean

        dim Children as boolean



        return Children

    end function

End class
```

Works fairly well.  To simply get some data:

```
    r = New RecordsNode
    r.FilePath = "C:\Test.xml"
    r.Load()

    TextBox1.Text = r.Band.Text
    TextBox2.Text = r.Band.Album.Text
    TextBox3.Text = r.Band.Album.Date.Text
```

*Note: To test create a project, add three textboxes and add the code to the Form_Load event.  Now add the class RecordsNode along with the Base classes in a separate file.  Lastly copy the XML to a file.*

The nice thing about this is it is easy for developers plus makes the code quite readable.

To add a node and fill a listbox (note the new node exists only in memory but will persist if the Save method is called).

```
    r = New RecordsNode
    r.FilePath = "C:\Test.xml"
    r.Load()

    r.Band.Add()
    r.Band.Text = "Metallica"

    For Each band As XmlClassListItem In r.Band._list
        ListBox1.Items.Add(band.Text)
    Next
```

A major flaw is the inability to access a child member in the loop.  If I want the Album or Albums for a band in the loop it is impossible to get.  I don't see an easy way to fix this.

Before I start from scratch and re-design the whole thing I was wondering if anyone can see a way to patch this up.

I can provide a C# version if anyone needs it.

Please dont tell me to use XSD.  I tried that and it makes sume ugly classes.  I don't know anyone who thinks having a class named **BatchPatientDataRequisitionDataOptionalDataUserField** makes code readable.

Comment: You can use `Paste Special` in Visual studio to paste the XML as a Class, it will autogenerate a class for you which is easily serialize/deserializable.

Comment: I didn't know you can do that, thanks for pointing it out.  It must use the same libraries as XSD though.  Makes some ugly classes unfit for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The way I like to use to work with xml:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part

Really easy, straight forward and clean. It basicly does all the job for you.

Comment: Cool link, it does do a lot except for one thing.  From what I read I still need to create a class.  
Thats what I'm trying to do.